# Memory usage: global variables

Tags: swift, memory

I am writing an app that requires access to a set of information from all classes and methods.
My query is, what's the most efficient way of doing this, so as to minimise memory usage?

I have taught myself coding and have, of course, come across numerous different methods to solve this whilst trawling the internet.  For example:

I could create a global variable such as `var info = ...`, which I'd place above a class definition, thus giving access from anywhere in the app.

Or I could create a singleton, `GameData` and have the data stored there, e.g. `GameData.shared.info`, similarly available from anywhere in the app.

Or I could load the information in the first `ViewController` and then pass it around as a parameter.

There are no doubt more methods that I haven't come across, but I wonder which is the most memory-efficient method, if indeed there is such a thing.  In my case, I won't need access to a huge amount of data - no more than say sixty or seventy records each with half a dozen fields of text or numbers.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not surprised this is being voted to close on the Opinion-based reason, but I believe asking which of three methods of storage is more memory-efficient is not opinion based (even though the answer is that as long as the life of the object is the same, the memory consumption is the same).

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Opinion based, use case dependent or just a question that is to broad are all valid reasons to close this question imo

Comment: "Which one of these three methods of storing these values is more memory-efficient" seems pretty succinct to me ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Using dependency injection, that is, passing it as a parameter to any object that requires it, would be the more memory conscious method, since the variable will stop existing "automatically" if you were to replace the whole hierarchy (as long as it's done correctly).

By using a singleton or a global variable, you would have to clear the value yourself.

If the value is not going to disappear during the lifetime of the application, then memory usage doesn't matter, but I would still advice against global variables and suggest using dependency injection.

Comment: But if you inject the same data into several objects then you will have a much higher memory consumption

Comment: If it's a class, you'll be passing the reference. If it's a value type Swift will use "Copy-on-Write", but you probably wouldn't use dependency injection on value types anyway.

Comment: The data will need to be accessed throughout the life-time of the app and so will only be cleared once the app is closed.  So, I'll continue with my singleton method.  Thank you.

Comment: Well I certainly agree that dependency injection in general is the best solution but it makes it overly complicated for a global data solution. And I don't really understand why structs can not be used for dependency injection.